# How to invoke the constructor of every parent exactly once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multiple-inheritance

Suppose one has a simple multiple inheritance setup, with two base classes `A` and `B` and one child class `C` inheriting from both.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Started A's constructor")
        # -- Not calling: super().__init__() --
        print("Ended A's constructor")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Started B's constructor")
        super().__init__()
        print("Ended B's constructor")

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Started C's constructor")
        super().__init__()
        print("Ended C's constructor")
```

Upon a call

```
c = C()
```

we get the output

```
Started C's constructor
Started A's constructor
Ended A's constructor
Ended C's constructor
```

If I want to call both of the base class constructors for each `C` object, and do not have access to the base class to add a `super().__init__()` call, what should be changed or added to `C`? Is there a way to do this such that it doesn't break if `A` indeed did call `super().__init__()`? 
(Edit: To be clear, adding `super().__init__()` to `A` would call `B`'s constructor as it is next in the MRO; to make this clearer: [code example](https://repl.it/repls/MatureCaringDirectories))

More importantly, in the general case where one wants to call each `__init__` method of every ancestor exactly once, and was unsure of whether each `__init__` function called `super().__init__()`, how would one ensure each parent class was called once and only once?

If this is not possible, would this not undermine fundamental object oriented principles? Simply, in this case, the implementation of `A` should not affect the behaviour of `B`.

Comment: You shouldn't call super in `B.__init__`. You will just be calling the `__init__` of `object`.

Comment: Why would the developers not choose for the `__init__` of `object` to do nothing if they did not intend for people to ever call it? Do you have any references or further insight into why it should never be called, and will not be called in any python libraries? Such an answer may be more suitable as an answer than a comment.

Comment: To use cooperative multiple inheritance with `super` then every class needs to call super. Put a `super().__init__()` call in `A.__init__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's only good advice if `A` knows that `B`'s constructor takes no arguments. If `A` and `B` are unrelated classes, that's a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexW I'm not saying it should not be called. Just pointing out it wont do anything, so is unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulRooney no, that is not how it works. You need to call `super` in `B` and `A` for the full MRO chain to be walked. **super does not mean call the immediate parent class**. It means *call the next in the MRO*. If your classes are going to use cooperative multiple inheritance, then `super` needs to be called

Comment: @PaulRooney: When you construct a `B`, the super call just calls `object.__init__`. In a multiple inheritance situation, which is the point of this question, the super call may call a different `__init__` than `object.__init__`.

Comment: @PaulRoony Perhaps this makes it clearer: https://repl.it/repls/MatureCaringDirectories

Answer (score 1):

`A` doesn't use `super`, so it can't be used for cooperative inheritance. Instead, define a wrapper for `A`, per [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). (Assuming you can't simply fix `A` in the first place.)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Started A's constructor")
        print("Ended A's constructor")


# AWrapper also needs to override each method defined by A;
# those simply delegate their work to the intenral instance of A
# For example,
#
#  def some_method(self, x, y):
#      return self.a.some_method(x, y)
#
class AWrapper:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.a = A()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class B:
    ...


class C(AWrapper, B):
    ...
```

Comment: Surely making `AWrapper` inherit from `A` is an easier solution that creating copies of every single one of `A`'s methods?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: That puts A in the MRO, and now you're back to dealing with A's `__init__` not using `super`.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah, but manually continuing the `super` chain is significantly less work than copying all of `A`'s methods, no? The only thing that needs to be fixed is the `__init__`; creating a complete copy of the class seems excessive.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: How do you plan to fix A's `__init__`? Overriding it doesn't replace it. It's still in the MRO, and it's still going to break the `super` chain.

Comment: @user2357112 `super().__init__()` to call `A.__init__`, followed by `super(A, self).__init__()` to call `B.__init__`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey That doesn't work in general, because `super` doesn't necessarily return a proxy to the first *statically* defined base class; it depends entirely on the MRO of `self`, which might be an instance of a class you don't even know about yet.

Comment: I don't follow. When you call `super().__init__()`, one of two things can happen: 1) `A.__init__` is called, or 2) some injected class's `__init__` is called, but then the injected class is responsible for correctly continuing the `super` chain. Where's the problem? Are you saying someone could *on accident* inject an unsuitable class between `AWrapper` and `A`? That seems far-fetched.

Comment: @chepner Can you modify Aran-Fey's solution to show what the flaw is? I find it quite clever indeed but can't quite understand what you're alluding to here. Thanks. https://repl.it/repls/ScientificAgonizingVolcano

Comment: The problem is that this is clearly a toy example, and I'm not going to endorse a solution that only works for this toy example. What if `A` and `B` have a common ancestor, and `A` calls its `__init__` explicitly. That method could end up being called twice. The whole point of `super` is to ensure that each method gets called *once*, in the order that they appear in the MRO. If you're going to use `super`, do it right, and that means not hard-coding calls to specific base-class methods.

Comment: But if `A` explicitly calls `object.__init__`, how can you avoid `object.__init__` being called twice? Just because your `AWrapper` used composition instead of inheritance doesn't mean `object.__init__` will only be called once. It'll be called once from `A.__init__` and once from `B.__init__`. I don't see how composition has any advantage over inheritance here.

Comment: Then that's another problem with `A`; you *can't* guarantee it won't be called twice, because you've broken the contract imposed by `super` by calling `object.__init__` explicitly. When designing classes with co-operative inheritance, use of `super` is an all-or-none deal. Either use it, or don't.

Comment: Please read the linked article to understand what the purpose of `super` is; it's not just a way to invoke a parent's method without naming the parent explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the `__bases__` attribute of the class object to call the `__init__` method of each of the parent classes:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Started C's constructor")
        for base in self.__class__.__bases__:
            base.__init__(self)
        print("Ended C's constructor")
```

so that `C()` outputs:

```
Started C's constructor
Started A's constructor
Ended A's constructor
Started B's constructor
Ended B's constructor
Ended C's constructor
```

Comment: I considered this, but this won't work if `A` calls `super().__init__()` as `B`'s constructor will be called twice. I will make the question clearer that this could be the case, though the general case that I wanted to focus on covers this possibility.

Comment: Do you mean that `A` is the parent class of `B`? If so, you should define `B` with `class B(A):`.

Comment: Not at all. If one adds the call to `A`'s constructor, it will call `B`'s constructor as it's next in the MRO. It is this counter-intuitive behaviour that I'm trying to navigate here.

Comment: @blhsing no, not at all. That isn't how `super` works. `super` calls *the next item in the mro*, not the super-class. The simplest solution is to have `A` call `super().__init__` in `A.__init__` then this will all work as you would hope.

Comment: @blhsing Perhaps this makes it clearer: https://repl.it/repls/MatureCaringDirectories

Comment: @AlexW the problem is with the name `super`, which in analogy to languages like Java, means "call the super' classes method", but what `super` means in Python is "call the *class which comes next in the method resolution order's* method. Cooperative multiple inheritance breaks a lot of the clean, theoretical ideas surrounding OOP. This is why some famously OOP-centric languages *simply don't provide multiple inheritance* (i.e. Java). What `super` let's you do is use cooperative-multiple inheritance in a clean way, but you must plan your classes to do this ahead of time

Comment: Thanks. Now I see what your question is about. Sorry about the misunderstanding.